# kernel: OF: overlay: WARNING: memory leak will occur if overlay removed

Tags: kernel, raspberry-pi

How can I find the cause of these errors?

`journalctl -p 3 -b`

```
Dec 12 15:19:22 raspberrypi kernel: OF: overlay: WARNING: memory leak will occur if overlay removed, property: /soc/i2c@7e804000/status
Dec 12 15:19:23 raspberrypi kernel: OF: overlay: WARNING: memory leak will occur if overlay removed, property: /soc/spi@7e204000/status
Dec 12 15:19:23 raspberrypi kernel: OF: overlay: WARNING: memory leak will occur if overlay removed, property: /soc/i2s@7e203000/#sound-dai-cells
Dec 12 15:19:23 raspberrypi kernel: OF: overlay: WARNING: memory leak will occur if overlay removed, property: /soc/i2s@7e203000/status
Dec 12 15:19:23 raspberrypi kernel: OF: overlay: WARNING: memory leak will occur if overlay removed, property: /soc/i2c@7e804000/status
Dec 12 15:19:23 raspberrypi kernel: OF: overlay: WARNING: memory leak will occur if overlay removed, property: /soc/sound/compatible
Dec 12 15:19:23 raspberrypi kernel: OF: overlay: WARNING: memory leak will occur if overlay removed, property: /soc/sound/seeed-voice-card,format
Dec 12 15:19:23 raspberrypi kernel: OF: overlay: WARNING: memory leak will occur if overlay removed, property: /soc/sound/seeed-voice-card,name
Dec 12 15:19:23 raspberrypi kernel: OF: overlay: WARNING: memory leak will occur if overlay removed, property: /soc/sound/status
Dec 12 15:19:23 raspberrypi kernel: OF: overlay: WARNING: memory leak will occur if overlay removed, property: /soc/sound/seeed-voice-card,bitclock-master
Dec 12 15:19:23 raspberrypi kernel: OF: overlay: WARNING: memory leak will occur if overlay removed, property: /soc/sound/seeed-voice-card,frame-master
Dec 12 15:19:23 raspberrypi kernel: OF: overlay: WARNING: memory leak will occur if overlay removed, property: /soc/sound/seeed-voice-card,channels-playback-override
Dec 12 15:19:23 raspberrypi kernel: OF: overlay: WARNING: memory leak will occur if overlay removed, property: /soc/sound/seeed-voice-card,channels-capture-override
```

Answer (score 0):

These are warnings, not errors, and don't need to be fixed.  This is the normal behavior for loading `dtoverlays` that modify properties on an existing device tree.

An explanation for the warnings is [here](https://support.xilinx.com/s/article/76560?language=en_US).

According to the output, it looks like your loading some SPI, I2C and Sound "drivers" to your kernel.  A common place to add `dtoverlays` is via the `/boot/config.txt` file.  Take a look for any

```
dtoverlay=
```

lines involving the above systems.  They are likely the source for these warnings.

[RPi config.txt and dtoverlay](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/config_txt.html#dtoverlay)

Alternatively, if you are seeing these in response to loading a piece of software, that software may be explicitly applying dtoverlays.  If this is happening during boot, review the entries in the journal directly before you see these warnings.  It's likely those services are loading the overlays.

[dtoverlay command](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#part3.5.1)